# How to use intentSender in order to get details about the sender?

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm developing two android projects in which I'm trying to send intent from one activity on the first app to service on the other app.
Now, imagine many apps with activity and so, my service wish to know who send the intent.
I'm not sure but maybe the intentSender might work but there's not much documentation about it.
What I have tried:

```
    Intent newIntent = new Intent();
    newIntent.setPackage("com.myApps.myApps2");
    newIntent.setAction("com.myApps.myApps2");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, newIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    try {
        startIntentSender(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),newIntent,0,0,0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And on the service side:

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String str = intent.getAction(); 
intent.getCreatorUid(); // Bad because this function belongs to IntentSender class..
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks